# subprocess a bash command with *

Tags: python, bash, expansion, subprocess

Is there a way, I can execute in python a bash command with expansion: `*`

I tried thousand ways with no luck.

Actually I want to have a python script [which](https://github.com/bk322/bk-goodies/blob/master/bk-act-on-dirs.py) enters each directory in the current dir, and executes a given bash command there (possibly a bash command with an expansion: `*`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Command line execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306178/python-command-line-execution)

Comment: Actually it's tough to tell how to solve your problem without seeing some code.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I don't think this qualifies as a duplicate, just because the answer is the same. We want people to be able to search for the question, not the answer, right?

Comment: @machine: They both ask how to use a glob with subprocess.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: if it is a duplicate then [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9547674/4279) should also answer [the question that you've linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306178/python-command-line-execution) but it is certainly not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os
from subprocess import check_call

cmd = 'echo *' # some shell command that may have `*`
for dirname in filter(os.path.isdir, os.listdir(os.curdir)):
    check_call(cmd, shell=True, cwd=dirname)
```

- `filter(os.path.isdir, os.listdir(os.curdir))` lists all subdirectories of the current directory including those that starts with a dot (`.`)
- `shell=True` executes command given as `cmd` string through the shell. `*` if present is expanded by the shell as usual
- `cwd=dirname` tells that the command should be executed in `dirname` directory

Comment: It works exactly as I wanted, but why there's nothing about `cwd` arg of `check_call` at [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call).

Comment: @Adobe: the docs explicitly mention *"The full function signature is the same as that of the [Popen constructor](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) - this functions passes all supplied arguments directly through to that interface."*

Answer (score 1):

Would you maybe have use for the [`glob` module?](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html)

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob("*")
['build', 'DLLs', 'Doc', 'ez_setup.py', 'foo-bar.py', 'include', 'Lib', 'libs','LICENSE.txt', 'NEWS.txt', 'python.exe', 'pythonw.exe', 'README.txt', 'Removesetuptools.exe', 'Scripts', 'selectitems.py', 'selectitems.pyc', 'setuptools-wininst.log', 'share', 'so_vector.py', 'tcl', 'Tools', 'w9xpopen.exe']
>>>
```

Comment: I'm aware of glob, but I wanted to give a bash command as an argument to a python script.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're going to have the shell execute the command, let the shell do the expansion of the shell metacharacters.  You can run:

```
sh -c "your_commaand -with *"
```

The shell will process the globbing for you and execute the command.

That leaves you with the problem of traversing the subdirectories of the current directory.  There must be a Python module to do that.

If you decide your program should `chdir()` to the sub-directories, you must be careful to come back to the starting directory after processing each one.  Alternatively, the shell can deal with that for you, too, using:

```
sh -c "cd relevant-subdir; your_command -with *"
```

This avoids problems because the shell is a separate process switching directories without affect your main Python process.

Comment: +1: it never occured to me - that I could feed it to the `bash -c`.